# Team Get-Item env:$variable doesnt work in all builds

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, teamcity

I have been able to get `env:$var` by using `Get-Item` command in Teamcity in one build configuration, but it fails in another. When I print the values I'am able to get the results but when I use `Get-childitem env:$var` it fails with the following error :

```
Get-childitem : Cannot find path 'TestDeploy_GhNew.promote.from.env' because 
[19:34:32][Step 2/4] it does not exist.
[19:34:32][Step 2/4] At C:\BuildAgent\work\4aa6addd2114a494\deploy\foo.ps1:23 char:29
[19:34:33][Step 2/4] +                     $var = (Get-childitem env:$env_var).value
[19:34:33][Step 2/4] +                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[19:34:33][Step 2/4]     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (TestDeploy_GhNew.promote.from.e 
[19:34:33][Step 2/4]    nv:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
[19:34:33][Step 2/4]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCh 
[19:34:33][Step 2/4]    ildItemCommand
```

I have tried declaring the parameters in the script window and `Get-Item env:$var` but does not help .

Answer (score 0):

Accordind to the error you can read `env:$var` but the folder it points ('TestDeploy_GhNew.promote.from.env') does not exist.

Comment: thank you for the reply , but its not a folder , its a variable whose value i am trying to read.

Comment: As I understand `env:$var` contains `TestDeploy_GhNew.promote.from.env` and `Get-ChildItem` can't read this folder. Test : `Get-ChildItem $env:CommonProgramFiles`.